# Time spent in voiceRoom isn't always registering when room is full discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, discord.js

**using discord.js + MongoDB + quick.db**
When a user enters a channel, a timer starts and goes to db, then when he exits it should write time spent in room to MongoDB. But it gets stuck in some cases. 
After it i update google sheet file and there are stats, but in some cases they get wrong, and i can't understand why.

````
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
       let newUserChannel = newMember.voiceChannel
       let oldUserChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel
       let channel = client.channels.find(x => x.id === '500086478492401676')
if (oldUserChannel === undefined && newUserChannel !== undefined) {
           if (newUserChannel !== undefined && oldUserChannel !== undefined) {
               if (oldUserChannel.id == newUserChannel.id) return
           }
           // let start = new Date()
           let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
               .setColor(0x00ff00)
               .setDescription(newMember + 'Зашел в ' + '**' + newUserChannel + '**')
               .setTimestamp()
               .setFooter(newMember.user.username, newMember.user.avatarURL)
           channel.send(embed)
           if (newUserChannel) {

               ata = collection.findOne({
                   id: newMember.id
               }).then(dataUser => {
                   if (!dataUser) {
                       let date = new Date();
                       let d = date.getDate();
                       let m = date.getMonth();
                       let y = date.getFullYear();
                       let today = new Date(y, m, d);

                       collection.insertOne({
                           id: newMember.id,
                           data: [{

                               created_on: today,
                               time: 0

                           }]
                       })
                   }
                   let start = new Date()
                   db.set(`${newMember.id}.time`, start)
                   db.set(`${newMember.id}.id`,newMember.id)
                   //let toPush = dataUser.data.push()
                   let list = (oldd, neww) => {
                       if (oldd.voiceChannel !== undefined && neww.voiceChannel !== undefined) {
                           if (oldd.voiceChannel.id === neww.voiceChannel.id) {
                               return
                           }
                       }
                       console.log(1)

                       if (db.get(`${neww.id}.id`) === neww.id) {

                           data = collection.findOne({
                               id: newMember.id
                           }).then(userDataDB => {
                               let date = new Date();
                               let d = date.getDate();
                               let m = date.getMonth();
                               let y = date.getFullYear();

                               let today = new Date(y, m, d);

                               if (!neww.voiceChannel) {

                                   let start = db.get(`${neww.id}.time`)
                                   let timee = Math.floor((new Date() - new Date(start)) / (1000 * 60))
                                   if (oldd.voiceChannel.id !== '485412448522731520') {
                                       console.log('NO AFKK')
                                       let total = timee
                                       let dbLast = userDataDB.data[userDataDB.data.length - 1].created_on
                                       if (dbLast.getDate() === today.getDate() && dbLast.getMonth() === today.getMonth()) {

                                           total = userDataDB.data[userDataDB.data.length - 1].time + timee
                                           collection.updateOne({
                                               id: neww.id
                                           }, {
                                               $pop: {
                                                   data: 1
                                               }
                                           });
                                       }
                                       collection.updateOne({
                                           id: neww.id
                                       }, {
                                           $push: {
                                               data: {
                                                   created_on: today,
                                                   time: total
                                               }
                                           }
                                       });

                                   }

                                   setTimeout(function () {
                                       client.removeListener('voiceStateUpdate', list);
                                   }, 300)
                               } else if (neww.voiceChannel.id === '485412448522731520') {
                                   if (oldd.voiceChannel.id === neww.voiceChannel.id) return
                                   console.log('AFK')
                                   let start = db.get(`${neww.id}.time`)
                                   let timee = Math.floor((new Date() - new Date(start)) / (1000 * 60))
                                   let dbLast = userDataDB.data[userDataDB.data.length - 1].created_on
                                   if (dbLast.getDate() === today.getDate() && dbLast.getMonth() === today.getMonth()) {
                                       total = userDataDB.data[userDataDB.data.length - 1].time + timee
                                       collection.updateOne({
                                           id: neww.id
                                       }, {
                                           $pop: {
                                               data: 1
                                           }
                                       });
                                   }
                                   collection.updateOne({
                                       id: neww.id
                                   }, {
                                       $push: {
                                           data: {
                                               created_on: today,
                                               time: timee
                                           }
                                       }
                                   });
                               } else if (oldd.voiceChannel.id === '485412448522731520') {
                                   if (oldd.voiceChannel.id == neww.voiceChannel.id) return
                                   start = new Date()
                                   db.set(`${newMember.id}.time`, start)
                                   console.log('OLD AFK')
                               }
                           })
                       }
                   }
                   client.on('voiceStateUpdate', list);



               })



           }
       }
})```

//I expect registering data in MongoDB but it's not.
````